# Is this a proper (non-awkward) translation?

Tags: traducción, gramática

Translate.com gives me this:

"Mis libros son el agua, los de los grandes genios es el vino. Todo el mundo bebe agua."

...for this:

“My books are water; those of the great geniuses is wine. Everybody drinks water.”

It seems good to me, although such "robots" often give awkward translations. Does this seem alright?

Comment: Al ser frase con sentido figurado y fuera de contexto, podría darse por buena pero me chirría que el verbo ser este en singular en ambos idiomas, por falta de concordancia con el sujeto: «Mi **s** libro **s** **son** el agua, lo **s** (libro **s**) de los grandes genios **son** el vino.» Por otra parte, creo que es una traducción demasiado literal, pero no tengo claro lo que se quiere expresar exactamente, así que no me atrevo a hacer una traducción alternativa.

Comment: I don't know Spanish very well yet, but I think I get your point, which all multilingualists do but few monolinguists do, namely that "automatic" translating is a very rough and raw and minimally effective tool. The phrase "knows just enough to be dangerous" comes to mind.

Comment: @Fran al utilizar el sustantivo agua y vino se está refiriendo al líquido en general, es por eso que no se pluraliza y está gramaticalmente bien. Esa frase no tiene ningún contexto específico, es como una frase célebre y creo que se refiere a: *"Yo no hago cosas tan increíbles como los genios, pero todos consumen (quieren, usan) lo que hago."*

Comment: @El_Mochiq No me has entendido. Lo que he querido decir no es que debe concordar con «agua» o «el agua», sino con «los libros» («los libros son...», «el libro es ...») y por tanto debe parecer «son» dos veces (esto es, justo como en tu respuesta). De otro lado, tu última frase en el comentario explica a qué me refería con la traducción literal: Quizás es mucho mejor esta traducción-interpretación alternativa (en mi opinión, lo es) que la que das en la respuesta.

Comment: As it's written, this question is simply asking for a translation--or verification of an automatic translation. We are not a translation service. It's appropriate to question automatic translations, but try to make your questions here very specific. Is there a particular part of the sentence that seems off to you, that you have reason to doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some errors, the correct translation would be:

*Mis libros son agua, aquellos de los grandes genios son vino. Todos (Todo el mundo) bebe/toma agua.*

it should not be translated as "el agua" since is `water`, not `the water` the same for `wine` and instead of "los de los" because it doesn't sound that good you should use `aquellos`. For `everybody` you could use "todo el mundo" or just "todos" depends wich one you like more and the region and the same for `drinks`, as an example here in Perú we use more "tomar agua" than "beber agua".

Comment: Thanks; I adapted your translation, and am using it here (this will be the image associated with an upcoming Kickstarter project): https://www.dropbox.com/s/9eqxx0t94pakzcp/TwainEnglishSpanish2.jpg

Comment: Lol, that is nice. Glad to help.